Laravel query builder: How to perform calculation on withSum() column?
I have these Models:
Product Model:
protected $fillable = ['id', 'name', 'qty', 'parent_id'];

public function parent() {
  return $this->belongsTo(self, 'parent_id');
}

public function children() {
  return $this->hasMany(self, 'parent_id');
}

How can I get the diff from the parent product to its children like:

Product 1: qty = 1000;

Product 2: child of Product 1, qty = 100

Product 3: child of Product 1, qty = 300


Expected query result
ike this:
Collection: {
  all: [
    App\Models\Product: {
      id: 1,
      qty: 1000,
      sum_children: 400,
      remaining: 600, // product_1_qty (1000) - sum_children (400)
      },...
  ],
}

I have tried the withSum methods like:
Product::withSum('children as ttl_children', 'qty') ->addSelect('qty - ttl_chilren');
But I can not perform the calculation like that.
Can anyone help me or point me on the right direction?
Thank you!

Since the sum of children quantity is computed not a database field, which prevents you from running raw queries for calculation. So I would suggest to use laravel collection methods on the result to achieve the expected result.
Solution 1 (Simple query, recommended for smaller data)
$products = Product::whereNull('parent_id')
  ->withSum('children as sum_children', 'qty')
  ->get()
  ->each(
    fn($product) => $product->remaining = $product->qty - ($product->sum_children ?? 0)
  );

Using this approach the result will look like this, containing remaining field:
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#7265
    all: [
      App\Models\Product {#7269
        id: 1,
        name: "ABC",
        qty: "1000",
        parent_id: null,
        created_at: "2024-10-25 13:51:29",
        updated_at: "2024-10-25 13:51:29",
        sum_children: 400,
        remaining: 600,
      },
    ],
  }

Solution 2 (recommended for large sets of data but have a very complex query.
$products = Product::whereNull('products.parent_id')
    ->leftJoin('products as children', 'products.id', '=', 'children.parent_id')
    ->select('products.*')
    ->selectRaw('COALESCE(SUM(children.qty), 0) AS sum_children')
    ->selectRaw('products.qty - COALESCE(SUM(children.qty), 0) AS remaining')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->orderByDesc('remaining')
    ->get();


thank you for your suggestion.
I have a question about your solution.
What if I want to order the record using the remaining value?
For example, let's say I have about 10k records, and I want to order by the remaining value from the DB and then fetch the result to the view, how can I do that?
Thank you.

@HùngThái Alright, for sorting you can use collection methods like sortBy('column') and sortByDesc('column')

I'm updating my answer if you really need to do it on db level, but it is going to cost you a very complex query.

Thank you for your time and solutions. I'm gonna try it now. Thank you.
